# How to expose RSK node to an external network?

Tags: rsk

I am having problems exposing my RSK node to an external IP.
My startup command looks as follows:

```sh
java \
  -cp $HOME/Downloads/rskj-core-3.0.1-IRIS-all.jar \
  -Drsk.conf.file=/root/bitcoind-lnd/rsk/rsk.conf \
  -Drpc.providers.web.cors=* \
  -Drpc.providers.web.ws.enabled=true \
  co.rsk.Start \
  --regtest
```

This is my `rsk.conf`:

```
rpc {
 
     providers {
         web {
             cors: "*",
             http {
                 enabled = true
                 bind_address = "0.0.0.0"
                 hosts = ["localhost", "0.0.0.0"]
                 port: 4444
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

API is accessible from localhost, but from external network I get error 400. How do I expose it to external network?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add your external IP to `hosts`. Adding just `0.0.0.0` is not enough to indicate all IPs to be valid. Port forwarding needs to be enabled for the port number that you have configured in `rsk.conf`, which in this case is the default value of `4444`.

```
rpc {
     providers {
         web {
             cors: “*”,
             http {
                 enabled = true
                 bind_address = “0.0.0.0"
                 hosts = [“localhost”, “0.0.0.0", “216.58.208.100”]
                 port: 4444
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

where `216.58.208.100` is your external IP